# Namespace prefix src not found

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2019

While entering some XAML code found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.combobox?view=netframework-4.8 the **src:** throws an error. Does anyone know why or is there a work-around?

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <src:IEvents x:Key="myIEvents"/>
</Grid.Resources>
```

Visual Studio Error: XDG0006 The namespace prefix "src" is not defined.

Note: I modified the example replacing StackPanel with Grid.

This is the updated XAML code snippet:

```
<Window x:Class="Task_Logger.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:src="clr-namespace:Task_Logger"
    mc:Ignorable="d"

    Title="Idle Time Category" Height="246" Width="376">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <src:IEvents x:Key="myIEvents"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource myIEvents}" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="37" Margin="31,20,0,0" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="311" Name="comboBox1" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=comboBox1, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
```

This is the class in the .cs file

```
namespace Task_Logger
```

```
    class iEvents : ObservableCollection<string>
    {
        public iEvents()
        {
            Add("Clog -­ Resin Pot Valves");
            Add("Clog -­ MVP Valves");
            .
            .
```

Comment: you should `src` (or probably your own namespace) to xml namespaces in xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IEvents` seems to be a custom type. You need to import it at the top of your page. `src:` is the placeholder, or, the local defined namespace alias.

It most likely you need something like this at the top of your page:

```
<Page x:Class="Project.Pages.Page"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 

  <!-- here is your src definition -->
  xmlns:src="clr-namespace:Something.Namespace.WhereIEventIsDefined"/>
```

Comment: I added the src definition in my code above. But it now throws an error saying iEvents doesn't exist in namespace Task_logger. However the class is defined in the .cs file.

Comment: Hey, did you manage to fix it?

Comment: The only problem I'm having now is getting the XML to recognize iEvents.